# Memory management for unnamed variable

Tags: objective-c, ios4, memory-management, memory-leaks

When I create a variable I want to assign to a property I can do the following (assuming the property is `@property (nonatomic,retain) UILabel *myLabel;`):

```
UILabel *temp = [[UILabel alloc] init];
self.myLabel = temp;
[temp release];
```

What would happen in the following scenario where `temp` is not used?

```
self.myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[myLabel release];
```

This is assuming I would add a `[myLabel release];` in `dealloc` due to the property.

Would this be proper memory management?  In the second example does `myLabel` have a retain count of 2 after the `init` line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second might happen to work, but is incorrect. The first line calls `setMyLabel:`. That may happen to set an ivar, it may not. It might do all kinds of things (it might make a copy, it might store the information elsewhere, etc). Your second line releases an `ivar`. If the setter happens to be implemented the way you're assuming, then you will get lucky and it will work. But this is not correct memory management.

The first example is correct. You can also use the autorelease pool to simplify things. Better is to move your code to ARC, which solves all of these problems faster and more easily.

Comment: +1 Memory management with ARC is indeed much easier to get right.

Answer (score -1):

Assigning to a `retain` property will automatically call `retain` on the object assigned to (and call `release` on the previous object). So yes, after

```
self.myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
```

`[myLabel retainCount]` will return 2, one from `init` and one from assigning the property. So you should either add `autorelease` to the line above, or call `release` before the function exits.

Comment: Absolute retain counts are meaningless.

Comment: See:  http://whentouseretaincount.com

Comment: Of course using it in code is a bad idea, this was just for illustration for how the memory management system works.

Comment: .... and using absolute retain counts to demonstrate how memory management works is exactly the problem.